# Populate List from pojo in given order

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, java-8

I have a POJO object having few fields and a list of string. We have to create a list of object using field values of pojo, in exactly same order as of list of string. Right now I am calling list.add with pojo getters while looping on list of String-

```
public class ResultSet {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    private String field4;


    public List<Object> populateResultList(List<String> list) {
        List<Object> resultSet = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String filedName : list) {
            if ("Field1".equalsIgnoreCase(filedName)) {
                resultSet.add(getField1());
            } else if ("Field2".equalsIgnoreCase(filedName)) {
                resultSet.add(getField2());
            } else if ("Field3".equalsIgnoreCase(filedName)) {
                resultSet.add(getField3());
            } else if ("Field4".equalsIgnoreCase(filedName)) {
                resultSet.add(getField4());
            }
        }
        return resultSet;
    }


    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public String getField3() {
        return field3;
    }

    public String getField4() {
        return field4;
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to achieve this as its lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: You received 3 answers, all of which solve the problem you posed. Are you waiting for something else before you accept one of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with plain Java 8 Stream API. You can defined mappings between `fieldName` String and `Function<ResultSet, Object>` that return a value associated with `fieldName`. Using function has this advantage that you can simplify it to a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) like `ResultSet::getField1` is an equivalent of following lambda expression:

```
Function<ResultSet, Object> f = resultSet -> resultSet.getField1();
```

In this way you can define mappings map like this one:

```
private static final Map<String, Function<ResultSet, Object>> mappings = new HashMap<String, Function<ResultSet, Object>>() {{
    put("field1", ResultSet::getField1);
    put("field2", ResultSet::getField2);
    put("field3", ResultSet::getField3);
    put("field4", ResultSet::getField4);
}};
```

Then your `populateResultList` method may look like this:

```
public List<Object> populateResultList(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .map(fieldName -> mappings.getOrDefault(fieldName.toLowerCase(), it -> null).apply(this))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

What happens here is for every `fieldName` in input `List<String>` we take a mapper defined in `mappings` map or we return a mapper like `it -> null` if a mapper for given `fieldName` was not defined. Calling `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` filters out all null elements from the result list.

#### Demo

Here you can find <kbd>[Demo](https://jdoodle.com/a/5OE)</kbd>

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

final class ResultSet {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    private String field4;

    public ResultSet(String field1, String field2, String field3, String field4) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
        this.field4 = field4;
    }

    private static final Map<String, Function<ResultSet, Object>> mappings = new HashMap<String, Function<ResultSet, Object>>() {{
        put("field1", ResultSet::getField1);
        put("field2", ResultSet::getField2);
        put("field3", ResultSet::getField3);
        put("field4", ResultSet::getField4);
    }};

    public List<Object> populateResultList(List<String> list) {
        return list.stream()
                .map(fieldName -> mappings.getOrDefault(fieldName.toLowerCase(), it -> null).apply(this))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public String getField3() {
        return field3;
    }

    public String getField4() {
        return field4;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResultSet resultSet = new ResultSet("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit amet");

        System.out.println(resultSet.populateResultList(Arrays.asList("Field1", "Field4", "Field3", "Field2", "Field9")));
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the java library [vavr](http://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/#_pattern_matching) and reduce your code to this:

```
public List<String> populateResultList(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .map(v -> Match(v).of(
                    Case($("Field1"), getField1()),
                    Case($("Field2"), getField2()),
                    Case($("Field3"), getField3()),
                    Case($("Field4"), getField4())))
            .collect(toList());
}
```

You can think of the Match expression as a Switch statement that returns a result. And the returned result is what we are mapping the values of the list to.

Comment: +1 for vavr, but Java 7+ can do `switch` case on `String` - there's no need for a third-party library to do pattern matching. Besides it's plain ugly - Java is not gonna be Scala no matter how much they try.

Comment: It's not about making java scala, they are finding ingenious ways of adding Scala structures to Java for people who like functional programming.
Switch doesn't return a value it is more of a spaghetti code used for this case.

Comment: You probably didn't read their docs or haven't interacted with the creator Daniel. He unabashedly admits that the library is heavily inspired by Scala; and I don't think it's a bad thing. Credit  where it's due.

Comment: Yes, if you check the link I posted you will see that their first example is how it is in Scala, and then how they ported it. But saying that they are trying to make out of java scala is a stretch. 
I disagree with some of their decisions e.g. Match being a method and Uppercase is very confusing. Otherwise, very useful functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a little reflection trickery, and don't want to hard-code field name to method reference, the following works, and will be more maintainable if you add more fields to `ResultSet` in the future.

```
public class Main {
    private static Map<String, Method> getterMap;

    static {
        try {
            getterMap = Arrays.stream(Introspector.getBeanInfo(ResultSet.class).getPropertyDescriptors())
                    .filter(pd -> pd.getReadMethod() != null && !"class".equals(pd.getName()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(pd -> pd.getName().toLowerCase(), PropertyDescriptor::getReadMethod));
        } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
            getterMap = Collections.emptyMap();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResultSet resultSet = new ResultSet("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit amet");
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("field1", "Field4", "Field3", "Field2", "field9");

        List<String> list1 = list.stream()
                .map(String::toLowerCase)
                .filter(getterMap::containsKey)
                .map(getterMap::get)
                .map(getter -> invokeGetter(getter, resultSet))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(list1);
    }

    private static String invokeGetter(Method getter, ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            return getter.invoke(rs).toString();
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```